# Continuos UI update Mac Application?

Tags: cocoa, macos

I want my Mac cocoa application to continuously update the View even if it goes to back ground? Something like Activity Monitor or DigitalColor Meter.

How can I achieve such behavior?

Thank you!

EDIT: I get context from NSGraphicContext and then create a thread to do the job in back ground.

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{   
    context = (CGContextRef)[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(ExecuteDrawingInBackGround:) toTarget: self withObject: nil];
}
```

Comment: I think we'll need more specifics on what you're trying to do, because most views will be redrawn as required regardless if the app is frontmost.

Comment: I have a thread in background which does some activity on views context. Now as I browse though other application, my application stops updating and once I click back it updates.

Comment: You can't update the UI from a background thread unless you call the UI update methods on the main thread using `performSelectorOnMainThread:`. Please post the code you're using to update the UI.

Comment: OK, but can you also show us what `ExecuteDrawingInBackGround:` does? (By the way, method names should never start with a capital letter.)

Comment: @Rob: ExecuteDrawingInBackGround (Messy, will lead to confusions): delegates calls to other methods. but as I said, I am using context (cached) from drawrect in that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the Mac UI API from a background thread because it's not thread safe.

Programs that redraw themselves continuously do so by having the background threads (if any) notify the main thread that something has changed and needs redrawing.  This is easiest done by having the background thread send [-performSelector:OnMainThreadWithObject:waitUntilDone:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-CJBEHAEF) to some object, usually the document or a view controller.

Alternatively, you can also use [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) to fire regularly and avoid background threads altogether.

Comment: Indeed, Activity Monitor almost certainly just uses a timer of some sort, and something like DigitalColor Meter can be implemented without even that, using event taps and display refresh callbacks to only update the view when it needs to be updated.